# R programming (beginner): using a for loop, only gave me back the last result from the list

Tags: r, dataframe

I used a for loop to go through 50 results, these are in the list vid_id. 
Now I want to get the stats from these id's (I use the tuber library).

```
for(i in vid_id){
   stas <- get_stats(video_id = i)
}
View(stas)
```

The problem I face when running this code is that I only get back the results from the last id (50). I want to create a list that gives me back all the stats from every row (containing an id) in vid_id. It would be awesome if someone could help me find a solution :)

Comment: You can create a vector `stas` and store each result into its position like stas[1] , etc.

Comment: `stas[[i]] <- get_stats(video_id = i)`, this may become horrendously slow depending on what sort of thing this `get_stats` is returning

Comment: @AaronHayman I tried it, where should I specify my dataset (vid_id)? And should I put this line in the for loop?

Comment: @LuckyLuke, Sorry, I assumed i is an integer due to not reading carefully, what I sugestted won't work. if you precede the for loop with `stas <- list()`, then in the loop use `stas <- append(stas, get_stats(video_id = i))`. That should work. this will be ineffecient due to growing a data object in a loop, but it should work. This is the same as the solution Soren has provided

Comment: @AaronHayman Thank you very much for your answer! It works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! This returns the dataframe.

```
all_stas <- list()
for(i in vid_id){
  stas <- get_stats(video_id = i)
  all_stas <- rbind(all_stas,stas)
}
View(all_stas)
df <- data.frame(all_stas)
```

Thank you all for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are assigning a value to stas *each time* the loop goes around and thereby re-writing over the previous value.  The solution is to move your variable assignment outside the loop and append the value as follows:

```
all_stas <- list()
for(i in vid_id){
   stas <- get_stats(video_id = i)
   all_stas <- append(all_stas,stas)
}
View(all_stas)
```

Note, here I've defined all_stas variable as a list because I don't know what "get_stats" function is returning and a list() should be able to handle everything you want to append.  If you're returning a data.frame, you might want to use the rbind() function instead

Comment: Thank you very much :) It works! I have one more question. I tried to put it into a dataframe after making a list 

dataFrame2 <- do.call ("rbind", lapply(all_stas, as.data.frame))
write.csv2(x = dataFrame2, file="videoList_new01.csv")
View(dataFrame2)

This way it is all put into one column named X[[i]]. Is there a way I can make seperate columns based on the ID for example?

Comment: It looks like you maybe found your ideal solution below?  But per comment here, I believe that before the rbind call if you insert a line: "stas$vid_id <- vid_id" will create the column you're looking for